# How to get transparent jframe on windows?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

do you know how to get a transparent jframe on windows? On macOS I got it by using those lines

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new Color(1,1,1,1));
```

It seems it does not work on windows :( how can i do that?

MacOS example

[image]

Windows example

[image]

My code:

```
    frm_languageSelector = new JFrame();
    pnl_buttons = new JPanel();

    frm_languageSelector.setUndecorated(true);
    frm_languageSelector.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    frm_languageSelector.setFocusable(true);
    frm_languageSelector.setSize(500,100);
    frm_languageSelector.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pnl_buttons.setOpaque(false);
    pnl_buttons.setSize(500, 100);
    pnl_buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));

    btn_enUS = new JButton();
    btn_enGB = new JButton();
    btn_it = new JButton();
    btn_fr = new JButton();
    btn_de = new JButton();

    btn_enUS.setBorderPainted(false);
    btn_enGB.setBorderPainted(false);
    btn_it.setBorderPainted(false);
    btn_fr.setBorderPainted(false);
    btn_de.setBorderPainted(false);

    btn_enUS.setToolTipText(lang.getWord("pnl_enUS"));
    btn_enGB.setToolTipText(lang.getWord("pnl_enGB"));
    btn_it.setToolTipText(lang.getWord("pnl_it"));
    btn_fr.setToolTipText(lang.getWord("pnl_fr"));
    btn_de.setToolTipText(lang.getWord("pnl_de"));

    pnl_buttons.add(btn_enUS);
    pnl_buttons.add(btn_enGB);
    pnl_buttons.add(btn_it);
    pnl_buttons.add(btn_fr);
    pnl_buttons.add(btn_de);

    frm_languageSelector.add(pnl_buttons);
```

Comment: `new Color(1,1,1,1)` is opaque white. Try `new Color(1,1,1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't set setOpaque on the main JPanel.

This works,good luck.

```
public class TransparentFrame {

    private static class InvisibleFrame extends JFrame {
        public InvisibleFrame() throws HeadlessException {
            setUndecorated(true);
            setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InvisibleFrame frame = new InvisibleFrame();

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));
        buttons.add(new JButton("1"));
        buttons.add(new JButton("2"));
        JButton exit = new JButton("exit");
        exit.addActionListener((e) -> frame.setVisible(false));
        buttons.add(exit);
        buttons.setOpaque(false);

        frame.setContentPane(buttons);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.toFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Basically with windows to get the same result I need to add my buttons to a panel an then add the panel to the frame instead to apply my buttons directly to frame. Thanks

Comment: Done and same thing... I found that is the grid layout which cause the border around the buttons... Any idea?

Comment: @Monstercat It's not `GridLayout`, it's mostly the buttons themselves which are drawing the border, maybe have a look at [`JButton#setBorderPainted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setBorderPainted-boolean-)

Comment: Just post a small demo code that is not working, otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: @Beowolve I added my code. On macOS it works properly, on windows not. I don't know precisely what is not working but i know that on windows transparency does not work

Comment: Ok I see, your problem is that Girdlayout will expand all Buttons to its possible maximum within that layout. You can force the layout to have gaps between the Buttons if you create it like this:

new GridLayout(1, 5, 10, 10)

Maybe there is a default gap on macOS, but I am not a mac developer, can't tell.